# Disable Panorama looping

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

Is there a way to disable the looping of panorama? I need that one cannot move from the first to the last element, and vice versa. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with the panorama control (at least not in an easy way).

The only thing you can do, is inherit the control (or the one from the Windows Phone Toolkit) and implement it yourself