# How to stop circular looping for panaroma item in Windows phone 8?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I am using Panaroma control to display list of items. The problem i am facing is that after last item it will again continue to display the items from first . I just want it will go from first to last item in one swipe direction and viceversa in another direction. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

That's the natural behavior of the `Panorama` control, and I suggest you not to manipulate it. Even if you do it'll be a concern from the user's perspectives as it's the usual behavior in a `Windows Phone` app.

[Disable Panorama looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407385/)

If you really wanted to, then have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23533705/prevent-scrolling-on-last-item-of-panorama-item-or-pivot-item-wp7-c-sharp) & [How to stop pivot looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669546/).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop looping items in a Panorama Control. But you can stop looping `Pivot` Items by simply setting `YourPivot.IsLock=true` when you are in the last Pivot Item.

And you can unlock the Pivot, by detecting the swipe direction.